# How to make a user control to refresh for every 5 mins?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I need a user control to fetch data from SQL Server every `5` mins but without refreshing the complete webpage.

The project is with 4.0 Framework and C# as server script.

**I need this one without using Timer Control.**

And Let me clarify one more thing.. This is purely Web Based Project (ASP.NET). Kindly don't answers for windows forms and some other technologies.

Comment: Using thread in your Code it's possible

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Yes but using same ajax and timer control.. But I need something efficient way to do this.

Comment: When you say "Ajax", are you talking about Ajax.net?

Comment: Asynchronous requests made by ajax server scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an Ajax request that you fire off using setInterval.
This will enable you to refresh just portions of the page.

Another approach is to use SignalR - a push framework that let's you push changes to the client from the server.
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

The advantage of that is that you don't need a fixed interval since you can have the server push the changes when they occur in real time.

Comment: As I mentioned.. I don't want to use timer and ajax requests.

Comment: You can consider a push framework like SignalR

Comment: It was ok.. but requesting external api will always consumes time.. so please give me some suggestions that how can I achive this without using any api's. I need a way within the framework.

Comment: I found answer here.. which was not satisfactory.. Thanks @TGH

Answer (score 1):

```
   var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
{
    MyMethod();   
}, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
```

And For Your Refresh Requirement You have to use AJAX. . it will not refreshing the whole page.

**Second Option**
There are a few ways to do this, you can create a timer that runs every 5 minutes and start it when the time reaches one of the 5 minute intervals, or have it run every few seconds and check if the time is divisible by 5

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); // create a new timer
timer.interval = 300000; //300000 = 5 minutes
then create a tick function and add an event handler

timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTickHandler); //add the event handler
timer.Start(); //start the timer
```

Comment: As I mentioned.. I don't want to use timer

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/75aff3c6-9537-4d86-94bf-13ec8a02d011/refresh-the-page-for-every-5mins-with-out-using-timer-control-in-windows-forms . . refer this link.I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to put ur user control into aspx page and put it in iframe ?, then u can set that page has refesh meta tag. 
Like this :

PageWithUserControl.aspx html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta id="MetaRefresh" http-equiv="refresh"content="21600;url=PageWithUserControl.aspx"         runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
// your usercontrol here
</div>
</form>
```

And cs code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string RefreshValue = Convert.ToString((2 * 60));
    // Refresh this page 60 seconds before session timeout, effectively resetting the   session timeout counter.
    MetaRefresh.Attributes["content"] = RefreshValue + ";url=PageWithUserControl.aspx?  q=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;


}
```

Then the page will be refeshed after time u set and data will be reloaded.

Comment: But this can be easily achieved by using page fragmentation in asp.net. Any alternative way..

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to query the clients cpu for the date and time using that to get every five mins